# Removing duplicates from a list in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, duplicates, text-mining

I am text mining from documents trying to collect company names from their annual reports using BeautifulSoup in Python. Am storing the collected names in a list, but I also am collecting duplicate names. I want to remove the duplicates from the list so that I have only unique company names. The names are of 3-4 words each. I tried using set() and similar looping techniques but it gives me a list of unique characters, not names. Please suggest a way to solve this issue.

`newlist = []
for i in etfname:
    if i not in newlist:
        newlist.append(i)
print(newlist)`[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwuxB.png)

Comment: What did you try with the sets? It sounds like you stepped one level too deep while iterating.

Comment: I have added a screenshot showing the list i have extracted from the file. I tried using the for loop and i got a list of unique letters, not names as a whole. Same happens with sets(). Please suggest a way to solve this issue.